# Emgu.CV How to read and save image from and to byte array?

Tags: emgucv

I'm learning Emgu.CV, I have successfully run the example, I prefer to read the image from byte array rather than direct from file, and also I prefer to save the result to byte array rather than to save directly to file..

any body can help?

Many thanks

```
            var _img = CvInvoke.Imread(_jpg);   // HOW TO READ FROM BYTE ARRAY

            var _fd = new Emgu.CV.CascadeClassifier(_face_classifier);
            var _img_gray = new UMat();
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(_img, _img_gray, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

            foreach (Rectangle _face in _fd.DetectMultiScale(_img_gray, 1.1, 10, new System.Drawing.Size(20,20)))
            {
                CvInvoke.Rectangle(_img, _face, new Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar(255, 255, 255));
            }

            _img.Save("result.jpg");  // SAVE TO BYTE ARRAY
```

Comment: I can understand how you might want to construct an image from a byte array but to "save to byte array"? Do you mean convert to a byte array? OR you literally want to write the byte stream to a file?

Comment: var _img = CvInvoke.Imread(_jpg);  this read from byte[]  and  this _img.Save("result.jpg");   this to byte array

Comment: You've just repeated yourself. An image is not a byte[], typically it is a byte[,,] where; byte[rows,cols,channels]... a 512x640 RBG image for example would be byte[512,640,3]. What are you expecting in terms of serializing the three dimensions to one dimension? Also, when you say "Save to byte array", that doesn't mean anything. Do you mean "convert to byte array", or "convert to byte array, and save to a file"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've understood your question to be in fact twofold: Converting an image to a `byte[]`, and saving a `byte[]` to a file. I'll address the easier and latter first:

### Saving a `byte[]` to File

```cs
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("OutputFile.dat",FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    BinaryWriter bs = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    bs.Write(byteBuffer);
}
```

### Loading a `byte[]` from File

```cs
byte[] byteBuffer;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("InputFile.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    // Where 0xF0000 is calculated as Image Width x Height x Bit Depth
    byteBuffer = br.ReadBytes(0xF0000); 
}
```

Now for the second part; I'm assuming you are familiar with pixel formats and how the true image structure of `byte[,,]` (or any other depth) is serialized to a single dimension `byte[]`. If not please do ask.

### Create an `Image` from `byte[]`

In the following example, the `byte[]` is created rather than loaded as above, the source of the `byte[]` is irrelevant so long as it is a correct serialization of a known image dimension and depth.

```cs
int width = 640;        // Image Width
int height = 512;       // Image Height
int stride = 640 * 3;   // Image Stide - Bytes per Row (3 bytes per pixel)

// Create data for an Image 512x640 RGB - 983,040 Bytes
byte[] sourceImgData = new byte[0xF0000];

// Pin the imgData in memory and create an IntPtr to it's location
GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(sourceImgData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

// Create an image from the imgData
Image<Rgb, byte> img = new Image<Rgb, byte>(width, height, stride, pointer);

// Free the memory
pinnedArray.Free();
```

### Convert an `Image` to `byte[]`

```cs
// Convert the source Image to Bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = sourceImage.ToBitmap();

// Create a BitmapData object from the resulting Bitmap, locking the backing data in memory
BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
    PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

// Create an output byte array
byte[] destImgData = new byte[bitmapData.Stride * bitmap.Height];

// Copy the byte array to the destination imgData
Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0,
    destImgData,
    0,
    destImgData.Length);

// Free the memory
bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```

Comment: @Don2 Did this give you what you needed? Any questions or is this answered?